# Angular2 Google Maps problems and required peers

Tags: node.js, angular, google-maps

When I do `npm install @agm/core --save` tells me that both `angular2-google-maps@0.17.0` requires a peer of `@angular/common@^2.3.1` and `@angular/core@^2.3.1` but none was installed.

Yes. I do have everything updated to angular4. I tried reinstalling but then the error changed to this one:

[Error I get from Angular Google Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl80F.png)

Any idea on how to solve this? I've seen other topics around here but any of the answers were voted nor they have helped me

Comment: I also had issues with agm, I ended up writing my own.

Comment: u mean writting your own google maps library for angular?

Comment: I didn't write whole library just the stuff I needed